# dockerd command failed to load listeners

Tags: docker

docker is installed with the admin account in a vm by following the link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/set-up-environment?tabs=Windows-Server&redirectedfrom=MSDN

Once installed , I am trying to start the docker daemon with the following command under admin account:

```
dockerd
```

And I am getting the following response:

```
time="2020-02-03T15:37:17.151865800+01:00" level=info msg="Starting up"
failed to load listeners: open //./pipe/docker_engine: Access is denied.
```

By the way I have configured the proxy settings by creating a config.json file as mentioned in the following link:

https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/

What should be done to avoid this "failed to load listeners: open //./pipe/docker_engine: Access is denied." even though dockerd is executed as admin user ?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?